# terminal command is overwritten on itself

Tags: bash, terminal

sometimes in terminal when I type a long command, instead of continuing in the next line it starts to write at the same line and I cannot see what I am typing. What is the reason and how should I make it fine?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `PS1` with colours? You might not have properly escaped zero-width sequences.

Comment: I am using ubuntu actually it is on the hpc terminal

Comment: Have you tried [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/downloads.html)?

Comment: I do not know about PS1. It happens only some times but when it happens I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Oh, no colours. What you do see for `printf '%q\n' "$PS1"`?

Comment: @brooksrelyt iTerm2 is macOS only, isn't it?

Comment: with PS1 command I get this :\ \[\\u@\\h\ \\W\]\\\$\

Comment: I have not tried iTerm2 yet.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Sorry yes, it is for macOS

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you resize a terminal window while in a fullscreen command (say inside "vim" or "less"), when you exit back to the shell it will assume your terminal has the old dimensions, and will show the behavior you are describing. See this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res

Also, please in the future post this kind of questions in unix.stackexchange.com as this one is not strictly a programming question.